# How do you calculate ability modifiers?

Tags: dnd-5e, ability-scores

I noticed that ability scores and the modifiers are different, but I know they relate to each other. How are ability modifiers calculated?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Have you read the basic rules or PHB? If so, what confuses you about how they explain the relationship between ability scores and modifiers?

Answer (score 8):

This is answered on page 13 of the PHB under the heading [Determine Ability Scores](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/step-by-step-characters#3DetermineAbilityScores) which starts on page 12:

> [...] To determine an ability modifier without consulting the table, subtract 10 from the ability score and then divide the result by 2 (round down).